# Importing data from SQLite to python using pandas?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, sqlite

I've just downloaded some data and it is named 'database.sqlite'.

Now, I am trying to import the data in this database to a data frame using Pandas. My code is below:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas

conn = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite')
df = pd.read_sql_query("select * from country", conn)
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select * from country': no such table: country
```

But I know that there is a table named 'country' as I am viewing the database on DB Browser for SQLite.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Have you tried using `read_sql` instead of `read_sql_query`?

Comment: @Plato77 yes, I get the same error.

Comment: Error messages don’t lie, so you’ll have to start with assumption that the table “country” does not exist in the instance of database.sqlite you are connecting to. Without having access to file system I would guess that the database that does have the table “country” exist in a different folder than your python module exists in. Try putting the full file path into your connection function and see you get the results you need.

Comment: It sound like there is something wrong with your SQL query or with the database file. Open the sqlite database on the command line using: `sqlite3 database.sqlite` then check the database schema using the command `.schema` (within the sqlite interface). You should check that you have the correct table name. Finally confirm your query works in the sqlite interface. Hopefully that should track down the problem! As Ethan says, listen to any error messages along the way.

Comment: @Ethan you're correct. For some reason, the database was in the wrong folder. Thanks!